# Is it possible to get an element from a string variable by index?

Tags: bash

If I have a variable with multiple string elements separated by spaces, is it possible to get an element by providing an index? Something similar you could do with arrays?:

```
my_var="string1 string2 string3 string4"
echo $[my_var[3]] # this does not work
```

Comment: Use an array for this.

Answer (score 2):

You use... an array.

```
$ my_var=("string1" "string2" "string3" "string4")
$ echo "${my_var[3]}"
string4
```

However, you might be asking, given your original string, can you split it into an array?

```
$ read -a arr <<< "$my_var"
```

This works, but only if *every* space in the string is to be treated as a delimiter. You can't quote some to treat as literal space; that's why arrays were added to the language in the first place.

You might be in luck and your string uses some *other* delimiter, e.g. a comma, in which case you can set the value of `IFS`:

```
IFS=, read -r -a arr <<< "$my_str"
```

but in general, strings-as-lists are fragile.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it using `read` command with setting the input-field-separator appropriately. It does't matter for your current input since the default  `IFS` handles the single white-space character between words.

```
IFS=' ' read -ra inputArray <<<"$my_var"
```

Setting `IFS=' '` is optional here, added it to stress the need for using it when splitting strings containing other de-limiters.

and access individual elements as

```
printf "%s\n" "${inputArray[0]}"
string1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want the third word, you can use

```
cut -d" " -f3 <<< ${my_var}
```